# Ag-grid setFilter in server side filtering

Tags: filtering, ag-grid, server-side

I just want to check if it's possible to give setFilter values in callback, in form of complex objects instead of array of strings. Reason why we need setFilter to have complex objects is because we are using server side filtering and we would like to show labels in filter, but send back keys to server to perform filtering.
If we have for example objects like {name: 'some name', id: 1} we would like to show 'some name' in filter UI but when that filter is selected we need associated id (in this case 1).

By looking into source code of setFilter and corresponding model, it seems like this is not possible.

Is there a way maybe I am missing that this could work?

ag-Grid version 23.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use cellRenderer. Set your IDs as values and then convert them into names in cellRenderer

```
const filterItems = [{id: '1', name: 'Value 1'}, {id: '2', name: 'Value 2'}];
...
filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
filterParams: {
  values: filterItems.map((item) => item.id),
  cellRenderer: (params: { value: string }) => {
    return params.value === '(Select All)'
      ? '(Select All)'
      : filterItems.find((item) => item.id === params.value)?.name;
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, from the interface it seems impossible indeed because of expected `string[]` values

```
interface SetFilterValuesFuncParams {
    // The function to call with the values to load into the filter once they are ready
    success: (values: string[]) => void;

    // The column definition object from which the set filter is invoked
    colDef: ColDef;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible, you will need to implement your version of it.